# How many number of nodes we can create under hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain

We are using hyperledger fabric. We have a doubt like, is there any limit, of creating number of nodes while configuring hyperledger fabric?

Comment: What is *hyperledger fabric*?

Comment: No idea but this sounds much more like a "how do I use this piece of software/hardware" question than a computer science question.